# sql : query same column multiple times AS different columns, with multiple values returned 1 per row

Tags: sql, moodle

I need to build a report that is structured as follows:

Name, Field_1, Field_2, Field_3

Jim, opt_1, y, 12

Jane, opt_2, n, 64

etcetera

I'm pulling from Moodle database tables, structure shown in following images. [mdl_user_info_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMDzQ.png), [mdl_user_info_field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnLte.png), mdl_user has same columns as others, all I'm getting from it is name so I'm not bothering to include it here. That part works fine.

Here's the best I could come up with so far, so you can see how the tables join:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT (u.firstname, u.lastname) Name, 
(SELECT d.data FROM mdl_user_info_data d JOIN mdl_user_info_field f ON f.id = d.fieldid WHERE f.shortname = "Field_1" GROUP BY d.userid), 
(SELECT d.data FROM mdl_user_info_data d JOIN mdl_user_info_field f ON f.id = d.fieldid WHERE f.shortname = "Field_2" GROUP BY d.userid),
(SELECT d.data FROM mdl_user_info_data d JOIN mdl_user_info_field f ON f.id = d.fieldid WHERE f.shortname = "Field_3" GROUP BY d.userid),

FROM mdl_user u 
JOIN mdl_user_info_data d ON d.userid = u.id 
JOIN mdl_user_info_field f ON d.fieldid = f.id
GROUP BY d.userid
ORDER BY `Name` ASC
```

I know I'm barking up the wrong tree with my sub-queries, but not sure what to do in place of the GROUP BYs. My current query will return all values of each given Field_x for in each row, when I need to return only the value that corresponds to the user named in column 1.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: For extra clarity: I know I could do   'GROUP_CONCAT(d.data ORDER BY d.userid) "Field_1, Field_2, Field_3",' but the project spec requires separate columns for each field, not a single comma separated concat column. I wish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive about moodle or it's sql syntax, but if common, you might get what you want by doing left-joins to the table multiple times, each with its criteria qualification, then just use the different ALIAS references to get your pieces...

```
SELECT 
      CONCAT (u.firstname, u.lastname) Name, 
      dFld1.Data as Field1Data,
      dFld2.Data as Field2Data,
      dFld3.Data as Field3Data
   FROM 
      mdl_user u 
         LEFT JOIN mdl_user_info_data dFld1
            ON u.id = dFld1.userid 
            LEFT JOIN mdl_user_info_field fFld1
               ON dFld1.fieldid = fFld1.id
              AND fFld1.shortname = "Field_1"
         LEFT JOIN mdl_user_info_data dFld2
            ON u.id = dFld2.userid 
            LEFT JOIN mdl_user_info_field fFld2
               ON dFld2.fieldid = fFld2.id
              AND fFld2.shortname = "Field_2"
         LEFT JOIN mdl_user_info_data dFld3
            ON u.id = dFld3.userid 
            LEFT JOIN mdl_user_info_field fFld3
               ON dFld3.fieldid = fFld3.id
              AND fFld3.shortname = "Field_3"
   ORDER BY 
      `Name` ASC
```

I have this query with LEFT-JOINs if any such links may NOT have a value.

As for the group by, this would only be required if there are multiple entries for one or more of the underlying tables for a given user and field 1, 2 or 3 entries respectively.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you! If you have any favorite SQL learning resources I'm also open to recommendations there.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution.

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname, f.fieldname1, f.fieldname2
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN (
    SELECT d.userid,
      MAX(CASE WHEN f.shortname = 'fieldname1' THEN d.data ELSE null END) AS fieldname1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN f.shortname = 'fieldname2' THEN d.data ELSE null END) AS fieldname2
    FROM mdl_user_info_field f
    JOIN mdl_user_info_data d ON d.fieldid = f.id
    WHERE f.shortname IN ('fieldname1', 'fieldname2')
    GROUP BY d.userid) f ON f.userid = u.id
```

Concat will work for MySql, but you should use database compatible functions - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#SQL_compatibility_functions

So use the result of

```
$DB->sql_concat('u.firstname', 'u.lastname');
```